# How can I mount a tmpfs to /tmp via fstab, writable to anyone?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I want to mount a tmpfs to `/tmp` and make it writable to users (or a specific user). The machine is a Raspberry Pi 3 with Debian 8.0 (Raspian). Whatever I try, `/tmp` is always mounted with permissions only for `root`.

I've tried the following `fstab` entries:

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev,noatime   0       0
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev,noatime,user,uid=1000,gid=1001,mode=1777   0       0
```

This always results in the following permissions:

```
$ ls -alh /tmp
total 36K
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root   500 Jul 19 10:17 .
```

But if I mount a tmpfs to any other location instead of `/tmp` (eg. `/var/opt`), it is writable to everyone:

```
$ ls -alh /var/opt
total 4.0K
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   40 Jul  3 12:18 .
```

How can I mount a tmpfs to `/tmp` so that it is writable to everyone?

Output of `mount`:

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /var/opt type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
```

If mounted with all the uid, gid and mode options:

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1001)
```

Edit: Does any Linux service set permissions to 755 on the `/tmp` directory on boot? Because these permissions are set even if I just symlink `/tmp` to `/var/opt`, which by itself was writable to anyone. After booting with a symlink from `/tmp` to `/var/opt`, the permissions on `/var/opt` are set to 755.

Answer (score 8):

Your original `/etc/fstab` line is correct:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev,noatime 0 0
```

For symlinks to `/tmp`, such as `/var/spool`, `/var/tmp`, and perhaps `/var/opt` (not sure), remove the symlink, replace it with an empty directory, and add a new line to `/etc/fstab` which creates another mount, e.g.:

```
tmpfs /var/spool tmpfs  defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=0755,size=64M 0 0
```

To find all such symlinks:

```
sudo find / -lname '/tmp*' 2>/dev/null
```

The reason this is necessary is that, at boot, permissions on some directories such as `/var/spool` are changed, and `chmod` on a symlink changes the target directory.

See also [Why is /tmp mounted with permissions 0755 when fstab has 1777?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490995)

Answer (score 5):

My tmpfs setting is:

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   rw,mode=1777,size=12g
```

The sizing is for a system with much more memory and swap that you are likely to have.  `noatime` or `relatime` shouldn't matter as the inodes will be memory structures and unlikely to be written to disk.  `tmpfs` is paged out to swap if necessary.

The permissions of 755 on `/tmp` are likely the default permissions on the mount point.  The traditional permissions are 1777 allowing anyone to create files, but securing them from manipulation by other users.